# MySQL count, group by and join query

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count, group-by

I have two tables: `users` and `comments`, where each comment belongs to a user.

#### users

```
id  user  class
1   mike    A
2   joe     B
3   john    A
```

#### comments

```
id  user_id    comment
1     1      "some text"
2     2      "some text"
3     1      "some text"
4     2      "some text"
5     3      "some text"
6     2      "some text"
7     2      "some text"
```

I wish to count number of comments in each user class.
The result should be:

```
A 3
B 4
```

I've tried this:

```
SELECT users.class, count(*) AS count 
  FROM comments 
 GROUP BY comments.user_id.class
 ORDER BY count DESC;
```

but does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make a Join like that

```
Select u.class, count(*) 
From users u
Join comments c on c.user_id = u.id
Group by u.class
```

Comment: Thank you very much, I really need to remember this stuff.

Comment: Look http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Visual_SQL_Joins/Visual_SQL_JOINS_orig.jpg

Answer (score 1):

You should `JOIN` two tables `ON` the id of each group :

```
SELECT u.`class`
     , count(*) AS `count` 
FROM `comments` c JOIN `users` u  ON u.`id` = c.`user_id` 
GROUP BY u.`class`
ORDER BY `count` DESC;
```

Comment: I think this works too but Miltons answer was first so that's the one I tried and selected as solution. Thanks to you too notulysses.